# How to reduce dictionary size in gensim?

Tags: python, dictionary, gensim

I'm fitting a Hierarchical Dirichlet Process (HDP) topic model using the python gensim package on the 20newsgroups dataset, and I discover that my topics are not very informative (the top word probability is very small).

I'm using standard text pre-processing that includes tokenization, stop-words removal, and stemming. I was thinking that reducing dictionary size can help generate more meaningful topics. What are some of ways of reducing the dictionary size in gensim?

Answer (score 4):

I found the following code helped reduce the dictionary size dramatically and achieve more meaningful topics:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docs, prune_at=num_features)
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=10,no_above=0.5, keep_n=num_features)
dictionary.compactify()
```

The first attempt at reducing the dictionary size is the prune_at parameter, the second attempt is the filter_extremes() function defined at:
[gensim dictionary](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html).